# Can I return all columns as rows and their values in the second column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create some reports for auditing, but I have a very specific question.

There's about 120 columns, each with a specific numeric answer. I'd like to return the column name and the value of the rows of that column. I'm aware I'll get a lot of results, but it's not a problem.

For example I have:

```
KEY |ColumnA | ColumnB
1   |Value A | ValueB
2   |ValueA2 | ValueB2
```

But want I want is:

```
1    |ColumnA | Value A
2    |ColumnA | Value A2
1    |ColumnB | Value B
2    |ColumnB | Value B2
```

I've tried returning all rows and then joining on itself, but it didn't provide me with the output I needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple `unpivot` will do the work :)

```
declare @tbl table ([Key] int, ColumnA varchar(15), ColumnB varchar(15));
insert into @tbl values
(1, 'Value A', 'ValueB'),
(2, 'ValueA2', 'ValueB2');

select [key], [column], [value] from
(select * from @tbl) p
unpivot 
([value] for [column] in (ColumnA, ColumnB)) u
order by [column]
```

Comment: Thanks! Would I need to declare every column I want? There's one key that binds the row currently and I need to keep that. I've updated my example. Sorry!

Comment: You're the best! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do what you want - you need to do a customized sorting for the columns names:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (ColumnA VARCHAR(20), ColumnB VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #temp VALUES ('Value A','Value B'),('Value A2','Value B2')

SELECT t.Col, t.Val
FROM (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) RNO FROM #temp t) tmp
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (tmp.ColumnA,'ColumnA',tmp.RNO),(tmp.ColumnB,'ColumnB',tmp.RNO)) AS T(Val,Col,sort)
ORDER BY T.Col, Sort
```

The result is as below,

```
Col       Val
ColumnA   Value A
ColumnA   Value A2
ColumnB   Value B
ColumnB   Value B2
```

Answer (score 0):

it's so simple...If you know the column names, you could use a simple UNION

```
SELECT * FROM tblAuditing


SELECT 'ColumnA' AS ColumnA,'ColumnB' AS ColumnA UNION
SELECT ColumnA AS ColumnA,ColumnB AS ColumnA FROM tblAuditing
```

[image]